# Apache2 and DACS mod_auth_dacs.so undefined symbol: ssl_hook_Fixup

Tags: apache, openssl

I am wondering why is it giving this error "undefined symbol: ssl_hook_Fixup" when I am trying to load mod_auth_dacs.so in httpd.conf

I installed everything accordingly to the DACS installation guide and apache2 is working with openssl and I can access my pages through https protocol.

There's a brief mention of the error in the DACS installation guide but it really isnt much of a help. Anyone experienced with this problem before?

Any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0):

**mod_auth_dacs** references symbols in **mod_ssl**, and apparently those symbols must be defined
before **mod_auth_dacs** is loaded.  This can be ensured by statically compiling **mod_ssl** into httpd
(configure httpd with --enable-ssl and verify with "httpd -l") and using

```
 LoadModule auth_dacs_module modules/mod_auth_dacs.so
```

in httpd.conf to dynamically load the mod_auth_dacs module.